# Dynamic force transmission simulation

Tags: simulation, physics

I have been working on this all day but I haven't figured it out yet. So I thought I may as well ask on here and see if someone can help.

The problem is as follow:

> ```
>                 ---------- 
> F(input)(t) --> |        | --> F(output)(t)
>                 ----------
> ```

Given a sample with a known length, density, and spring constant (or young's modulus), find the 'output' force against time when a known variable force is applied at the 'input'.

My current solution can already discretise the sample into finite elements, however I am struggling to figure out how the force should transmit given that the change in transmission speed in the material changes itself with respect to the force (using equation c = sqrt(force*area/density)).

If someone could point me to a solution or any other helpful resources, it would be highly appreciated.

A method for applying damping to the system would also be helpful but I should be able to figure out that part myself. (losses to the environment via sound or internal heating)

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried, and how you have applied the equations of motion to the discrete parts? There are so many details missing where it is impossible to answer at this point.

Comment: Look up online implementations for a MMS (Multi-Mass-Spring).

Answer (score 1):

I will remodel the porbem in the following way:

```
                   ___                      ___
  F_input(t) -->  |___|--/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\--|___|
```

At time `t=0` the system is in equilibrium, the distance between the two objects is `L`, the mass of the left one (object 1) is `m1` and the mass of the right one (object 2) is `m2`.

```
                         ___                      ___
  F_input(t) -->  |<-x->|___|--/\/\/\/\/\/-|<-y->|___|
```

During the application of the force F_input(t), at time `t > 0`, denote by `x` the oriented distance of the position of object 1 from its original position at time `t=0`. Similarly, at time `t > 0`, denote by `y` the oriented distance of the position of object 2 from its original position at time `t=0` (see the diagram above). Then the system is subject to the following system of ordinary differential equations:

```
x'' = -(k/m1) * x + (k/m2) * y + F_input(t)/m2
y'' =  (k/m2) * x - (k/m2) * y
```

When you solve it, you get the change of `x` and `y` with time, i.e. you get two functions `x = x(t),  y = y(t)`. Then, the output force is

```
F_output(t) = m2 * y''(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't well defined at all. For starters for `F_out` to exist, there must be some constraint it must obey. Otherwise, the system will have more unknowns than equations.

The discretization will lead you to a system like

```
M*xpp = -K*x + F
```

[image: eq1]

with `m=ρ*A*Δx` and `k=E*A/Δx`

But to solve this system with `n` equations, you either need to know `F_in` and `F_out`, or prescribe the motion of one of the nodes, like `x_n = 0`, which would lead to `xpp_n = 0`

As far as damping, usually, you employ proportional damping, with a damping matrix proportional to the stiffness matrix `D = α*K` multiplied by the vector of speeds.